# How to change the language in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

How can I change the language in WordPress for word "All Departments", "On Sale", "Top Rated", etc? I'm using the Media Center theme.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I would recommend posting this in https://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score -1):

You can try the Poedit software which is free to download and can translate any WordPress theme easily.